# Facebookの Test App では Emailなどにアクセス出来ない？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

FacebookのAPPを作成してRailsのローカル環境でテストする時はメインのアプリの他に"Create Test App"からテスト用のアプリを作成してその設定でSite URLをローカルアドレスにして作業するのが推奨されてるとどこかで読んで従っていたのですが、

Facebookの email や user_profile 情報は開発者のメールアドレスを登録して一般公開した状態でしか取得できないということも先ほど知りました。

だとすると email や user_profile を使った動作の確認をローカル環境では使えなくなってしまうと思うのですが、どのように対処するのが一般的なのでしょうか？

とりあえず思いつくのは本番用のFacebookのAppのSite URLの設定をローカルに書き換えて動作確認を行うという方法ぐらいなのですがもっと良い方法があれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> とりあえず思いつくのは本番用のFacebookのAppのSite URLの設定をローカルに書き換えて動作確認を行うという方法ぐらいなのですがもっと良い方法があれば教えて下さい。

私がfacebookのappを作る時は本番用とテスト用の二つを作って、テスト用のappのsite urlをローカルにしてますよ。

Comment: なるほど、Facebookが用意したTest用のアプリを使わずに普通に二つ別々に作れば良いんですね。公式の方法に従わないのは少し気持ち悪いのですがその方法を使うことにします。